# ¿Cómo separar las palabras de un texto y convertir a cada palabra en un elemento de un vector?

Tags: r, string, lista

Tengo la siguiente frase:

`It is tricky for authors to figure out which keys will work, and how their values will be specified. Lamentably, it may be necessary to read the source code of an R package like rmarkdown to understand all of the details. However, usually, there is some relief in the fact that there is one example working document to exemplify the settings for a particular back end and authors can adjust and modify those values. The key:value pairs may may a difference at several stages in the compilation process.`

He intentado tener todo el texto en un vector.

Lo que he hecho es ponerlo todo en un vector. De la siguiente manera:

`x<-c("It is tricky for authors to figure out which keys will work, and how their values will be specified. Lamentably, it may be necessary to read the source code of an R package like rmarkdown to understand all of the details. However, usually, there is some relief in the fact that there is one example working document to exemplify the settings for a particular back end and authors can adjust and modify those values. The key:value pairs may may a difference at several stages in the compilation process.")`

Después usé la función strsplit para separa cada palabra, de la siguiente manera:

```
palabras<-strsplit(x, "\\s")
```

Que me resulta:

```
[1] "It"          "is"          "tricky"      "for"         "authors"     "to"          "figure"      "out"        
 [9] "which"       "keys"        "will"        "work,"       "and"         "how"         "their"       "values"     
[17] "will"        "be"          "specified."  "Lamentably," "it"          "may"         "be"          "necessary"  
[25] "to"          "read"        "the"         "source"      "code"        "of"          "an"          "R"          
[33] "package"     "like"        "rmarkdown"   "to"          "understand"  "all"         "of"          "the"        
[41] "details."    "However,"    "usually,"    "there"       "is"          "some"        "relief"      "in"         
[49] "the"         "fact"        "that"        "there"       "is"          "one"         "example"     "working"    
[57] "document"    "to"          "exemplify"   "the"         "settings"    "for"         "a"           "particular" 
[65] "back"        "end"         "and"         "authors"     "can"         "adjust"      "and"         "modify"     
[73] "those"       "values."     "The"         "key:value"   "pairs"       "may"         "may"         "a"          
[81] "difference"  "at"          "several"     "stages"      "in"          "the"         "compilation" "process."
```

Pero no sé como de ahí convertirlo todas esas palabras en un vector.

Es decir tener un vector de 88 elementos.

No sé que paso más hacer...

¿Existe alguna función que me permita resolver este problema de manera sencilla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, el resultado es una lista de un elemento. Voy a adjuntar los resultados de las funciones que me indicas en una imagen en la publicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente `strsplit()` retorna una lista, pero en este caso con un único elemento, que es un vector de caracteres. Si quieres, puedes extraer directamente ese primer elemento:

```
palabras <- strsplit(x, "\\s")
class(palabras)
[1] "list"

palabras <- palabras[[1]]
class(palabras)
[1] "character"
```

O también podrías usar `unlist()`:

```
unlist(palabras)
```

**¿Por que te retorna una lista?** simplemente por que es capaz de procesar un vector con múltiples elementos, en tu caso solo hay uno:

```
strsplit(c("Hola que tal", "como te va?"), "\\s")

[[1]]
[1] "Hola" "que"  "tal" 

[[2]]
[1] "como" "te"   "va?"
```

Para este caso donde hay multiples elementos de origen, la extracción mediante `[[` deberías hacerla para cada elemento de la lista, en contra partida `unlist()` en este caso retorna un único vector completo

```
unlist(strsplit(c("Hola que tal", "como te va?"), "\\s"))
[1] "Hola" "que"  "tal"  "como" "te"   "va?"
```

Comment: Nuevamente gracias. Es de gran ayuda!!!!!